# Exchange data between components

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm having a component called user, there is a form handles by its render method. Once the form is submitted, I'm passing the message type by the user to an array. So every time the user passes the submit button, this array should be appended with the message typed in the input box.

but I need to send the content of this array to another component and display there. (content of the array return by the handleSubmit(event)). Still I'm without a clue. Can someone please direct me. Is this possible to do?

Home.js is the parent js file. It calls the User.js and Chat.js

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { User } from './User';
import { Chat } from './Chat';
export class Home extends Component {
  displayName = Home.name
  render() {
      return (            
          <div >
              <div class="user-container">
                  <User />
              </div>
              <div class="chat-container">
                  <Chat />
              </div> 
        </div>
    );
  }
}
<span class="border"></span>
```

User.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: '',
      messages: []
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="frame1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">
              Message
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                name="message"
                placeholder="Enter your Message"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    var newArray = this.state.messages.slice();
    this.setState({ messages: this.state.message }, () => {
      newArray.push(this.state.messages);
      this.setState({ messages: newArray }, () => {
        alert(this.state.messages);
      });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Chat.js

```
import * as React from 'react'
export class Chat extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div></div>);
    }
}
```

What I need to do is display the messages state of User.js to Chat.js

*Even a better way to do this is highly appreciated*

Comment: [Lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: See here: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to share the data between sibling components either you should [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or use some other solutions like Redux. I am providing an example here. As you can see we move the `messages` state to the parent component. With a handler function, we get the `message` from the child component and update our state in the parent.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messages: [],
  };

  handleSubmit = message =>
    this.setState( currentState => ( {
      messages: [ ...currentState.messages, message ],
    } ) );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <User onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Chat messages={this.state.messages} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Chat = props => (
  <div>
    <ul>{props.messages.map( message => <li key={message}>{message}</li> )}</ul>
  </div>
);

class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    message: "",
  };

  handleChange = evt => this.setState( { [ evt.target.name ]: evt.target.value } );

  handleSubmit = ( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit( this.state.message );
    this.setState( { message: "" } );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.message}
            name="message"
            placeholder="Enter your Message"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update after comments**

I wrote `Chat` component as a functional one since it does not use any state and lifecycle methods. You can write it as a class function by simply extending it from `React.Component` and using a `render` method.

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.props.messages.map( message => <li key={message}>{message}</li> )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm having a question. I'm getting an error message saying, const  cannot be used in .s file when  const Chat = props => ( is used. As do I need to mention this in the Chat.js file

Comment: You are welcome. Just update your question with the code you are having the problem. It is hard to understand like this.

Comment: Hi... Can you please let me know, where this 'const Chat = props => (...' need to be put. Is it inside the Chat.js?

Comment: No, it is the Chat conponent itself. I wrote it as a functional conponent.

Comment: Hi Can you please let me know ow it can be written as a class as well. Is the prop need to be written with the constructor and super inside it?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but as I can see you have figured out it. You are welcome.

Comment: Hi ... for the learning purpose, can you update your answer, mentioning how I can change 'const Chat = props => (...'  as a normal class. And if it is taking two parameter how can I write it?

Comment: I've added the class-based example. I did not understand the two parameters part. By saying parameter do you mean props?